# call js function in html from .js file

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, I know how to register my js file in my html and call functions in the .js from my html file.   Here I am trying to do the opposite , I have a function in the .js file and I want to call a function that is in my html file.  How do I go about registering the html (it's actually .aspx )  but that really shouldn't matter  for the scope of this question.

Comment: what's the problem you encounter? you should be able to call it directly as long as the function in your html parsed first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that the JavaScript function in your HTML is defined on the page before the code in the .js include calls it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply include your external script to the page at the end your body tag or at any place after your function declaration.

**Aspx page**:

```
<body>
    content content
     <script>
        /* Function to be called */
        function s(){
           alert('Hello World!');
        }
     </script>
     <script src="myJS.js"></script>
</body>
```

**myJS.js**:

```
/* Call a page function */
s();
```

By the time your external file is loaded your function `s()` will be declared.